# Angular 8 duplicated path when navigating to page

Tags: routes, angular8, angular-routing

I have a simple application with two pages with lazy loading. Whenever I navigate to a page or make a change to the app the path is duplicated, then if I make another change to the app it doesn't load anything and I see a blank page.
app-routing.module is:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: "first-page", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: 'first-page', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/first-page/first-page.module').then(m => m.FirstPageModule) },
{
    path: "second-page",
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/second-page/second-page.module').then(m => m.SecondPageModule)
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
```

If I open my window on localhost:4200 it navigates to first-page, correctly. The url is `localhost:4200/first-page`. Then if I make a change in the app causing the reload, the url becomes `localhost:4200/first-page/first-page`, and I still can see my page correctly. But if I make another change and the app reloads, then I get a white page with the url being `localhost:4200/first-page/first-page`, and the only thing I can do is to delete the path and reload the page.
The same thing happens if I navigate directly to `localhost:4200/first-page`: it duplicates the path and then if I change something in the app I get the blank page.
Why is it duplicating the path?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this behavior by removing the `--base-href` parameter from my command:

`ng serve --base-href` -> `ng serve`