# Angular router uses wrong guard

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a problem with guard in routing module. The issue is that the guard is triggered on every route of lazy loaded module while it should not.

From the app-routing.module.ts :

```
  {
    path: '',
    children: [],
    canActivate: [RedirectGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'x',
    loadChildren: () => import('./xmodule/xmodule.module').then(m => m.xModule)
  }
```

and in x module:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
    data: {
      roles: [
        Role.TEST_ROLE
      ]
    }
  },
```

The problem is that RedirectGuard runs on every route, so basically when I enter localhost:4200 - it runs, but when I enter localhost:4200/x it also runs.

Can someone help?

EDIT:

I have checked and even on basic setup like:

```
  {
    path: 'testing',
    component: TestingComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/testing',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

in app-routing.module there is something wrong. When I type localhost:4200 it redirects me to localhost:4200/testing, but then when I refresh page it is redirecting me to: localhost:4200/testing/testing, where it should stay on localhost:4200/testing....

Comment: [Order of Router Events](https://angular.io/api/router/Event)...

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz with this issue please, I'm having trouble reproducing the problem

Comment: You implementation is wrong. Please rewrite it. I could expect something like this to work: `canActivate: [RedirectGuard], children: [
  { path: 'x',  loadChildren: () => import('./xmodule/xmodule.module').then(m => m.xModule) }, // maybe others child routes 
] }`. Would also be helpful if you post a stackblitz demo.

Comment: I have troubles with reproducing an issue, but even if I disabled guards something strange is happening. When I ented localhost:4200/x it is autmatically taking me to localhost:4200/x/x page which is not correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268282/angular-8-duplicated-path-when-navigating-to-page the issue is actually almost the same but still don't have a solution.